# VS Reversing FatalExecutionEngineError address

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reverse-engineering

I'm working on very large piece of software that dynamically loads and uses a handful of dlls at runtime.

VS 2022 compiles and runs this software without any issues in Debug. When compiled and ran in Release though, I receive a FatalExecutionEngineError with not much more than a memory address and thread number.

Because of the scale of this application, I would rather not try to locate where this error is originating from by randomly inserting logging statements.

I believe that with the right tool, I can see the function that this took place in from the memory address provided by VS. Is that correct? If so, are there any tools that people would recommend?

Alternatively, is there an easier way to pinpoint the source of this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to see what code executed before the crash.